# Oracle: a litte confused about privileges granted to my user

Tags: oracle, permissions

I want to give few permission to my non-dba user on my database.
I give create session, create table, view, etc..
This query seems to confirm

```
SELECT privilege from USER_SYS_PRIVS;

    PRIVILEGE
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE PROCEDURE
CREATE VIEW
CREATE TABLE
CREATE SESSION
```

but I see I can create roles and user as not privileged user

```
create role mich identified by blablabla;

Role created


SQL> create user mich1 identified by blablabla;

User created
```

Is not too much for a simple user the permission to create user and roles?

As a DBA user I try to revoke...

```
SQL> revoke create user from myuser;
revoke create user from myuser
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01952: system privileges not granted to 'MYUSER'
```

I check if my user has dba role(I do those command as dba user)

```
SELECT granted_role FROM dba_role_privs where grantee='MYUSER';

GRANTED_ROLE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IMP_FULL_DATABASE
RESOURCE
MICH
EXP_FULL_DATABASE
CONNECT

SQL> revoke DBA from myuser;
revoke DBA from myuser
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01951: ROLE 'DBA' not granted to 'MYUSER'
```

I remove the roles MICH and RESOURCE, from my "unprivileged" user
but he still can create other users and roles.

Another strange thing:

as a non privileged user i did..

```
SQL> select * from SESSION_PRIVS;

PRIVILEGE
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AUDIT SYSTEM
CREATE SESSION
CREATE TABLESPACE
ALTER TABLESPACE
DROP TABLESPACE
CREATE USER
BECOME USER
ALTER USER
DROP USER....
```

-- other 69 lines..

as a sysdba I did..

```
revoke CREATE USER from myuser
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01952: system privileges not granted to 'MYUSER'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.
I remove the CONNECT from user

```
revoke CONNECT from myuser
```

and I will assign the privileges as I need

```
grant create session, create table to myuser
```

now create user give permission insufficient (error ORA-01031) when I try it as a non dba user

Answer (score 0):

Your user obviously has the DBA role. Look into this

```
SELECT granted_role FROM dba_role_privs where grantee='xxx';
```

where xxx is the name of your user (in capital letters usually)

Comment: No, I add now the lines in my question, thanks for answer, anyway

Comment: I have removed the roles MICH and RESOURCE from my user, but it still can create other rules and users.

Comment: Roles can be granted roles and it’s not just the DBA role that can create users. You need to do a connect by or recursive with query to get to all the possible grants. Think about what a user needs to be able to do in order to import a database, the `IMP_FULL_DATABASE` role gives them this (you can check what system privileges and roles that has grants to)

Comment: It is role IMP_FULL_DATABASE

Comment: No, it was the role CONNECT, but also IMP_FULL_DATABASE permit the creation of role and user